# TypeError: childrenFuncResult.filter is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

I have the following React-Admin component. I want to use 'permissions' to restrict access to certain resources based on this [demo](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Permissions.html#restricting-access-to-resources-or-views).

```
<Admin
    dataProvider={dataProvider}
    authProvider={authProvider}
>
    {permissions => (
        <>
            <Resource
                name="customers"
                list={VisitorList}
                edit={permissions.admin === 'true' ? VisitorEdit : null}
                icon={VisitorIcon}
            />
            {permissions.admin === 'true'
                ? <Resource name="categories" list={CategoryList} edit={CategoryEdit} icon={CategoryIcon} />
                : null}
        </>
    )}
</Admin>
```

The above code gives me the following error message:

```
react_devtools_backend.js:4026 TypeError: childrenFuncResult.filter is not a function
    at CoreAdminRouter.js:85:1
    at step (CoreAdminRouter.js:43:1)
    at Object.next (CoreAdminRouter.js:24:1)
    at fulfilled (CoreAdminRouter.js:15:1)
```

I am not sure what it means. (Note the code is the same as provided in the documentation) This is what my 'permissions' object looks like:

```
{
  "admin": true,
  "iss": "https://securetoken.google.com/prototype-XXXXXXX",
  "aud": "prototype-XXXXXX
  "auth_time": 1662121211,
  "user_id": "iVLBTt2XXXXXXXXXxzSsmJVHI3",
  "sub": "iVLBTtXXXXXXXXXxzSsmJVHI3",
  "iat": 166XXXXX11,
  "exp": 166XXXXx11,
  "email": "admin@org.com",
  "email_verified": false,
  "firebase": {
    "identities": {
      "email": [
        "admin@org.com"
      ]
    },
    "sign_in_provider": "password"
  }
}
```

Comment: change `permissions.admin === 'true'` to `permissions === 'admin'`  and `edit={permissions.admin === 'true' ? VisitorEdit : null}` to `edit={permissions === 'admin' ? VisitorEdit : null}` as mentionned in the documentation

Comment: No @monim, that did not help. I tried it

Comment: Seems like something similar was addressed here:https://github.com/preactjs/preact/issues/1932

Comment: @AasthaBist Yes looks similar but with respect to a different library. Tried the solution but did not help

Answer (score 0):

You're apparently on react-admin v3 (the error message mentions CoreAdminRouter, which doesn't exist anymore in react-admin v4). The syntax for setting resources based on permissions was different in v3:

```
<Admin
    dataProvider={dataProvider}
    authProvider={authProvider}
>
    {permissions => [
        <Resource
            name="customers"
            list={VisitorList}
            edit={permissions.admin === 'true' ? VisitorEdit : null}
            icon={VisitorIcon}
        />,
        permissions.admin === 'true'
            ? <Resource name="categories" list={CategoryList} edit={CategoryEdit} icon={CategoryIcon} />
            : null
    ]}
</Admin>
```

See https://marmelab.com/react-admin/doc/3.19/Authentication.html#restricting-access-to-resources-or-views for the right documentation for your version.